# Como obter o primeiro resultado de linhas duplicadas?

Tags: sql-server

**Situação**:

Em uma tabela há uma lista de itens com seus respectivos valores faturados em nota fiscal. Essa tabela possui um único campo que varia de acordo com a inserção dos dados, podendo repetir todas as outras colunas e não possui uma `PK`. Um exemplo seria:

```
fk_nota_fiscal | fk_produto | valor | campo2 | campoXXX
244060         | 0010101    | 100,00| X      | A       
244060         | 0010101    | 100,00| X      | B     
244060         | 0010101    | 100,00| X      | C
```

**Desejado**:

Eu preciso obter apenas o primeiro resultado independentemente da variação   da coluna `campoXXX`.

**Problema encontrado:**

Utilizando as funções `ROW_NUMBER()` e `OVER()`, agrupei os resultados em uma `CTE` e consegui selecionar apenas o primeiro resultado, porém o desempenho é absurdamente lento e inviável para uma quantidade considerável de registros.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk_nota_fiscal,fk_produto ORDER BY fk_nota_fiscal,fk_produto) AS ROWID

SELECT * FROM FROM CTE_vwItensRefaturar WHERE ROWID = 1
```

Comment: você possui um indice para `fk_nota_fiscal` e `fk_produto`?

Comment: Não, TobyMosque. Estou vendo sobre isso e se de alguma forma otimiza a performance.

Comment: Veja a possibilidade de criar uma pk ou indice clusterizado, envovendo fk_nota_fiscal, fk_produto e outro campo (campoXXX?). não vejo como você obter um ganho significativo substituindo á sua estrategia atual por qual quer uma das sugeridas nas respostas (inclusive, exceto pela sugestão dada pelo @OnoSendai, você terá uma perda ao invés de ganho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um *sub select com top 1* para fazer isso junto com o `group by do select`,

```
select fk_nota_fiscal,  fk_produto, valor,  campo2,
(select top 1 campoXXX from @teste t2 
        where t2.fk_nota_fiscal = t1.fk_nota_fiscal and t2.fk_produto = t1.fk_produto) 
from @teste t1
group by fk_nota_fiscal,    fk_produto, valor,  campo2
```

Ou usar a função [FIRST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) do sql server, mas mesmo assim terá que usar um sub select.

```
Select * from
    (
        SELECT   fk_nota_fiscal,
                 fk_produto,
                 valor,
                 campo2,
                 FIRST_VALUE(campoXXX) OVER (ORDER BY fk_nota_fiscal ASC) AS campoXXXX   
        FROM     @teste
    ) d
    GROUP BY fk_nota_fiscal,
             fk_produto,
             valor,
             campo2,
             campoXXXX
```

Uma solução, não sei se viável para sua estrutura, seria a criação de uma tabela(espelho) da sua tabela, como isso você poderia executa sua `query`  para fazer os inserts dos dados desejados e uma TRIGGER na sua tabela original para atualizar essa tabela quando houver alteração, com isso você poderia fazer o select direto na sua tabela(espelho).

Comment: Goku, com `FIRST_VALUE`, ele não necessita de uma subconsulta, na verdade substituir o `ORDER BY` pelo `PARTITION BY`, porém este comando só está disponivel no `SqlServer 2012` e infelizmente tem muita gente presa no `SqlServer 2008` (e anteriores), mas ainda assim, é uma alternativa interresante, porém não acho que terá um desempenho melhor que o `ROW_NUMBER` (devido as otimizações realizadas pela `Engine` do `SqlServer`).

Comment: @TobyMosque, a syntax do FIRST_VALUE obriga ter um ORDER BY (The function 'FIRST_VALUE' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.), bom não sabia qual versão ele estava usando e também não pensei em outras pessoas que user versões inferiores.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou isso? (Essa sintaxe pode variar dependendo do banco de dados, esta é para sql server)

```
SELECT TOP 1 fk_nota_fiscal, fk_produto, valor, campo2, campoXXX
FROM table_name;
```

Ou distinct?

```
SELECT DISTINCT fk_nota_fiscal, fk_produto, valor, campo2
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` funciona apenas caso todas as colunas sejam idênticas. O `TOP` retornará apenas a `N` ocorrência informada de toda a tabela, eu preciso trazer o primeiro registro de todos.